# Adobe Brackets - Autocomplete CSS tags in JavaScript file

Tags: autocomplete, adobe-brackets

I've been using Brackets for some time now, like it very much, but I could like it even more :)

I am doing a lot of a/b testing so I write most of my code in JavaScript, that also means I have to write CSS inside a JavaScript file and I'm wondering if there is any chance for autocomplete to show me hints not only for JavaScript but also for CSS?

Thanks in advance for any help

Cheers

Comment: How is the CSS embedded in the JS code? Are you doing something like `elem.style.cssText = "..."` or `$(elem).css("property", "value")`, or ...?

Answer (score 0):

I think that Brackets doesn't have an extension to support it yet but there is re sharper which is available for visual studio and some other ides which does the job.